# How to loosen DC barrel jack to fit with 12 V adapter?

Tags: power, connector, adapter, plug

I have a DC jack such as this:

[image]

The lot that I bought are all too tight to fit a 12 V Adapter plug into them. Plug:

[image: Adapter plug]

How do I loosen the jack? Are they always stiff when new? Should I buy new ones? The same jack is on a board (HW-131) and it fits perfectly. Kindly help me out.

Comment: You don't.  You buy jacks or plugs with the right dimensions.  There are maybe a half dozen "standards" in that same DC barrel connector size range, all varying by fractions of a millimeter.  You gotta get it "right" for reliable operation.    Look at the specifications for the jack/plug and the dimensions will be very clearly stated.

Comment: The jack is probably not the correct one for the plug. Barrel jacks are tricky, because the nominal OD *and* ID of the connectors has to match.

Comment: You are probably mixing up 2.1mm and 2.5mm jacks and plugs. They measure the same from the outside I believe, but the inside is different.

Comment: DONT DO IT!!!  As others have said, the plug snd socket are visually very as similar BUT are incompatible. When buying jack's you need to establish the actual dimensions of both. It is an likely but not certain that the plug is 2.5mm and the jack 2.,1mm

Comment: You can buy sockets with a 2.1mm pin, and a long-travel outer contact spring, that means they will accept plugs with either a 2.1mm or 2.5mm hole, but they are lower current than the normal correct size ones due to the smaller contact area that you get. Best buy the correct size ones.

Comment: Thank you people. You are a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two especially common (one might even say de facto standard) sizes for barrel jacks¹, that *look* like they ought to be intercompatible, but aren't. These are 5.5/2.1 mm and 5.5/2.5 mm. It's likely you have a 5.5/2.5 mm jack and a 5.5/2.1 mm plug.

The first number in the size (note that it isn't always formatted like this; this is just how I'm writing it. It may be the second number.), 5.5 in both cases here, is the outer diameter of the barrel plug. This is the dimension that's easiest to see from looking at it.

The second number, here 2.1 or 2.5, is the diameter of the pin in the center of the jack. (though "2.1" jacks seem to have a 2.0 mm pin much of the time, going by a very brief survey of parts available on digikey.)

A plug with a hole for a 2.1 mm pin can't accept a 2.5 mm pin without damage, even though the outer diameter looks the same. A plug for a 2.5 mm pin might physically fit over a 2.1 mm pin, but the electrical contact will be poor.

---

Also of note, though possibly not relevant to your question, is that there is no standard for whether the center contact is positive or negative. Most devices with barrel jacks expect the center contact to be positive, but some (notably Sony branded devices) expect the center to be negative. Make sure you have the polarity right, or you might damage whatever you plug it into!

---

¹There are, of course, many other common sizes. These two seem to be the most common, however.

Comment: Thank you. I will take my adapter to the market and buy whatever fits.